# Create multiple records in the database with same :id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, psql

I am trying to create several instances of the same record on my rails app. I have `tests` and `questions`. `tests` can have many `questions`.

I also have `testsessions`. My `testsessions` table looks like this:

```
id | user_id | test_id | question_id | answer
```

I am trying to get the controller to create several instances of the same testsession, with the only thing differing being the `question_id`, which will be pulled from the questions that have the same `test_id` as the testsession.

At the moment I have this in my controller:

```
def new
  @test = Test.find(params[:test_id])
  @testsession = @test.testsessions.new
  @testsession.user_id = current_user.id

  @testsession.save
  @questions = @test.questions
  redirect_to action: :index
end
```

But I don't know how to make it create several instances based on the `question_id`.

I have an array of the `question_id` that I want to use:

```
@questions = Question.where(test_id: @test.id).pluck(:id)
```

But I don't know how to put this into the controller...in the end I would want the table to look something like this:

```
id | user_id | test_id | question_id | answer
1  |    1    |    1    |      1      |
1  |    1    |    1    |      2      |
1  |    1    |    1    |      3      |
1  |    1    |    1    |      4      |
```

Answer is always empty because this will be input by the user later using `update`

Any ideas on how to do this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: so you want tesession which has one question_id and in one content field which can be as serialized hash or array depending on your content, which will have questions

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean...

Comment: `@testsession.question_id = @test.question_id, @testsession.content = @test.questions` where `content` will be a field on `testsession` which will be serialized hash or array depending on your `@test.questions` data, can you get it now what I mean

Comment: I don't think my question was clear enough...I want to create several testsession records, using the array of question_ids that I have from the test record.

Comment: @Sontya I've edited the question a little...

Comment: then loop through the questions array and create testsessions for each question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think I understand what you're trying to achieve: you have a test that has_many questions. When someone does the test, you want to create a test session for every question in advance.

Try this:

```
def new
  @test = Test.find(params[:test_id])

  @test.questions.each do |question|
    @test.testsessions.create user: current_user, question: question
  end

  redirect_to action: :index
end
```

As a side note: the `new` controller action isn't really a good place to create things, because `new` is (normally) accessible through HTTP GET requests.

Assume for a moment that the app you write is accessible to Google. If Google finds a link to this controller action, it will visit it and accidentally create new test session objects. Possibly many times.

This is why controller actions that create or change something in your app should only be accessible through other methods, like a  POST — search engines and other robots won't touch those.

Even if your app is not accessible in public, it's a good habit to get into.

Comment: Perfect!! Thank you so much! I've been struggling on this for ages and my method was becoming a huge monster trying to figure it out but this does exactly what I wanted!

Comment: @camillavk my pleasure. I've added another note that might be helpful; also, whenever you are juggling with IDs as you did originally, there is a good chance you are making it harder for yourself than necessary. `Question.where(test_id: @test.id).pluck(:id)` vs. `@test.questions` is an example of that. Let Rails do the hard work for you :)

Comment: I was just wondering if there was a way to force the new testsessions that are created in that method to all have the same :id?

Comment: @camillavk how do you mean? Every object must have its own unique ID; no two model objects of the same class can share one. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Yes, sorry I realised that after I posted the comment and forgot to go back and delete it...I think I've found another way to solve my problem :-)